# RMI: operation on list as result of method call has no effect

Tags: java, rmi

I created a simple example to experiment with the RMI feature of Java. It's quite nice. But when I call a remote method which *returns* a LinkedList object and I add an element to the list: nothing happens - the element isn't added. See my code bellow:

The Interface and implementation on the server (remote object):

```
public interface FooBar extends Remote {
    List<Object> getList() throws RemoteException;
}

public class FooBarImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FooBar {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -200889592677165250L;
    private List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();

    protected CompanyImpl() throws RemoteException { }

    public List<Object> getList() { return list; }

}
```

Code to bind it (server):

```
Naming.rebind("//" + hostname + "/foobar", new FooBarImpl());
```

Client code:

```
FooBar foo = (FooBar) Naming.lookup("//" + hostname + "/foobar");
foo.getList().add(new String("Bar"));

System.out.println(foo.getList().size());
```

The output will be `0` instead of `1`. So my simple question is: how to fix it without using an `add` method (because with an `add` method on the server side it works)?

**EDIT 1:**
This code works pretty well:

```
public class FooBarTest {

    static class FooBarImpl {
        public List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
        public List<Object> getList() { return list; };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooBarImpl test = new FooBarImpl();

        test.getList().add(new String("Foo"));
        System.out.println(test.getList().size()); // = 1
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:** This code works also (but I'm trying to replecate the simple code from EDIT 1):

```
@Override
public void add(Object o) throws RemoteException {
    list.add(o);
}

FooBar foo = (FooBar) Naming.lookup("//" + hostname + "/foobar");
foo.add(new String("Bar"));

System.out.println(foo.getList().size()); // == 1
```

Comment: Are you adding anything in `list` at server side? If yes then show your code

Comment: No. My scenario is as simple as described on the top.

Comment: Why should the list be empty? On object initialization the new `LinkedList` is created and only returned. As you can see in EDIT 1 it works for a simple scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> The output will be 0 instead of 1

This is so because , You are adding the element `Bar` to the anonymous `List` object obtained via `foo.getList()` but you are printing the size of the fresh `List` object obtained again via `foo.getList()` which is empty within following line:

```
System.out.println(foo.getList().size());
```

You should use following code:

```
List<Object> list = (List<Object>)foo.getList();
list.add(new String("Bar"));

System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: Am i missing something? i think he is doing the same thing.

Comment: @zerocool Watch my post carefully I have obtained the `List` object from `foo.getList()` and added `Bar` to that `list` and then printing its size .. it is in contrary to OP code..He is adding  `Bar` in an anonymous `List` object .. ;) and printing the size of fresh `List` object obtained again via `foo.getList()`

Comment: Yes this works, but I want to change the list object on the server and not my local object.

Comment: @mythbu : then in that case , you send the filled up `list` object from client to back to server and create a method on server where you will receive  the `list` object from client.

Comment: @Mac: that's an idea, but I'm tring to replicate the simple example (EDIT 1) for now.

Comment: @mythbu: You are changing the state of `foo` on your local system..Then how you expect the change to be seen on server without being sending it back to server??